# A trigger that'll update a column with a path

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to update the column 'path' with the path as soon as an item gets added to the table. I'm using mySql and PHP for this.

```
"id"    "name"         "description"               "level"  "parent"    "country"   "path"
"1"     "Kitchenware"   "Kitchenware description"   "1"       "0"         "US"        "Kitchenware"
"2"     "Knives"        "All our knives"            "2"       "1"         "US"        "Kitchenware > Knives"
"3"     "Butter Knives" "All Butter Knives"         "3"       "2"         "US"        "Kitchenware > Knives > Butter Knives"
"4"     "Cut em all"    "Cut em all"                "4"       "3"         "US"        "Kitchenware > Knives > Butter Knives > Cut em all"
"5"     "Cull em all"   "Cull em all"               "4"       "3"         "US"        
"6"     "Smear em all"  "Smear em all"              "4"       "3"         "US"        
"7"     "Meat Knives"   "All Meat Knives"           "3"       "2"         "US"        
"8"     "Cut em meat"   "Cut em meat"               "4"       "7"         "US"        
"9"     "Cull em meat"  "Cull em meat"              "4"       "7"         "US"        
"10"    "Smear em meat" "Smear em meat"             "4"       "7"         "US"
```

Any ideas on on a good way to do this?

In this table, Level 1 is the top most. 2 and 3 are heading. 4 are items.

I'm a little stuck with doing this (the selects inside a trigger). It needs to run after each insert. Not all at once.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of something that would happen in this trigger?

Comment: @Aushin I need to update the column path with the path. Scroll right to see path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a stored procedure not a trigger since it has a limitation :

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

but with a stored procedure you can:

> Although some restrictions normally apply to stored functions and
>   triggers but not to stored procedures, those restrictions do apply to
>   stored procedures if they are invoked from within a stored function or
>   trigger.

[DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `build_path`(IN row_id INT, IN path_name VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

UPDATE `my_table` SET `path`=path_name WHERE `id`=row_id;

END$$
```

And a example call is `CALL build_path(1,'Kitchenware');`

Assuming that you already have the path constructed if you don't the procedure can be altered to construct the path.

**UPDATE:**

Query that constructs the path . NOTE: the number of **self-joins = MAX(level)**

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        m1.path,
        IF(m2.path IS NULL,'',CONCAT(' > ',m2.path)),
        IF(m3.path IS NULL,'',CONCAT(' > ',m3.path)),
        IF(m4.path IS NULL,'',CONCAT(' > ',m4.path))
    ) as za_path
FROM 
    my_table as m1
LEFT JOIN my_table as m2
    ON m2.parent = m1.id
LEFT JOIN my_table as m3
    ON m3.parent = m2.id
LEFT JOIN my_table as m4
    ON m4.parent = m3.id
WHERE 
    m1.id = 8
```

Comment: Actually, it's how to construct the path that has my brain in knots. I'm fine with creating triggers or stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks. With a little bit of tweaking, this'll do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this hop this sample will solve your problem

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgforyou ON YourTable
FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @ID INT
SELECT @ID=inserted.iID From inserted


update Table set "name = '',description='',level='',parent='',country=''path='' Where iid = @ID
```

Comment: first of all you cannot modify a table that is already used from a trigger : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html. Second thing you update all columns with a empty string